# Disable all months in drop down which occurs after the current month

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined month drop down list in view like this

```
<select id="dlMonth" onchange="OnChangeDownloadTimesheetOption('month')">
                    <option value="1">Jan</option>
                    <option value="2">Feb</option>
                    <option value="3">Mar</option>
                    <option value="4">Apr</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">Jul</option>
                    <option value="8">Aug</option>
                    <option value="9">Sept</option>
                    <option value="10">Oct</option>
                    <option value="11">Nov</option>
                    <option value="12">Dec</option>
                </select>
```

and year drop down like this

```
<li style="float:left;margin-left:2%">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedYear, @Model.year, new { id = "dlYear", onchange = "OnChangeDownloadTimesheetOption('year')" })</li>
```

Now I want to disable all the months which has not yet occured for the current year in the javascript page.And for the previous years it must not disable any of the months.
I have written code somewhat like this in javascropt page

```
function TimesheetDownloadPageOnLoad() {
    debugger;
    var todayDate = new Date();
    var year = todayDate.getFullYear();
    var selectedYear=$("#dlYear").val();
    if (selectedYear == year)
    {
        $("#dlMonth").attr('disabled','disabled')
    }
```

Please help me with the coding.

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot just "help you with the code": here your expected output is quite clear, but tell us why your attempt did not work.

Comment: @dgiugg If the OP knew what was wrong they'd probably not have asked the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I simply meant that if you try a code, it is useful (and part of the "research effort") to say why it does not work: does it produce another result than the expected one, does it raise an exception...?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can use `getMonth()` to get the current month as an integer from a Date object. You can then use jQuery's `:gt()` selector to get all months after that from the `select`, before disabling them using `prop('disabled')`. Try this:

```js
function TimesheetDownloadPageOnLoad() {
 var month = new Date().getMonth();
 $('#dlMonth option:gt(' + month + ')').prop('disabled', true);
}

TimesheetDownloadPageOnLoad();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dlMonth">
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="4">Apr</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="7">Jul</option>
  <option value="8">Aug</option>
  <option value="9">Sept</option>
  <option value="10">Oct</option>
  <option value="11">Nov</option>
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Comment: One more help @Rory, I want this disabling according to the year like if it is previous year then it should not disable any of the month. :)

Comment: 1) What year? The select only shows months. 2) I'd suggest you start a new question for that, as it was not in your original request.

Comment: Sorry I cannot post question as I have reached my limit.

Comment: No, start a new one. You're asking for something completely different which renders any previous answers redundant.